# Buildblocks filtered by Category Name in Combobox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I  made a Userform with a combobox for Selecting Buildingblocks and inserting them into the word document in specified location. I am struggling with following issue:

**Inserting into Combobox buildingblocks by Category Name.**

Currently I am refereing to then Categories index, and I am not 100% satisifed:

```
Sub DataLoad()
  With Startup.CmbDutyCond ' refer to combobox
    For i = 1 To oTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes.Item(wdTypeTables).Categories.Item(2).BuildingBlocks.Count
      Set oBuildingBlock = oTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes.Item(wdTypeTables).Categories.Item(2).BuildingBlocks.Item(i)
      .AddItem oBuildingBlock.Name
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

The code works; It inserts list of buildingblocks by category. But what if I add a new category? The  index number may change and it will display a wrong list of building blocks in the Combobox. How can I write a code which will display list of building blocks by >>>Specified NAME<<< of the category, instead of by index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Category object has a Name property. You can use the Name (string value) as an argument for Item instead of the Index number.

```
oTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes.Item(wdTypeTables).Categories.Item("Specified NAME").BuildingBlocks.Item(i)
```

Comment: It works. I tried this solution before but is seems I mistaken category name and I thought I cannot put specified name there. Thank you!